# При вызове TThread.Queue не возвращает значение из потока в основной

Tags: delphi, многопоточность, delphi-xe8

С главной формы приложения создается вторичная форма:

```
var
  modal: TForm2;
begin
  modal := Tform2.create(application);
  try
    modal.showmodal;
  finally
    modal.free
end;
```

В ней по нажатию на кнопку создается поток, который должен будет обращаться к базе и работать с данными. для отображения на интерфейсе пользователю из потока должны передаваться текстовые значения статусов работы.

реализовано следующим образом:

```
TForm2 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    Memo1: TMemo;
    Label1: TLabel;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
  private
    MyThread: TMyThread;
  end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FreeAndNil(MyThread);
  MyThread := TMyThread.Create(False);
end;

procedure TMyThread.Execute;
var
  obj: TUpdatingAddressData;
begin
  obj := TUpdatingAddressData.Create;
  LogEvent('Изменение структуры таблиц');
  obj.AlterTable;
  LogEvent('Завершено');
  obj.Free;
end;
```

где:

```
procedure TMyThread.LogEvent(EventText: string);
begin
  TThread.Queue(nil,
    procedure
    begin
      Form2.Memo1.Lines.Add(EventText);
      Form2.Label1.Caption := EventText;
    end);
end;
```

Данная реализация не обновляет `Caption` и не добавляет в `Memo` значение. Однако если реализовать тот же код в главной форме приложения, обновление текста происходить будет.

Чем отличаются главная форма приложения и вторичная для создаваемых потоков в данном случае? Как корректно реализовать передачу строк из потока в форму?

Comment: *Несколько упрощу -* Запомните главное, все действия с формами и контролами должны вестись только из главного потока. Внутри потоков, оборачивайте все вызовы к формам/контролам в `Synchronize(..)`.

Answer (score 1):

Передача данных из потока **в его конце** с помощью Queue - не очень хорошая идея.

Дело в том, что поток тут же уничтожается, а поставленные в очередь события  стираются (`RemoveQueuedEvents(Self)` в деструкторе `TThread`).

Поэтому здесь лучше сделать `Synchronize` (который ждёт исполнения процедур) или передавать данные в `OnTerminate` (который на самом деле обёрнут в тот же `Synchronize`).

Если уже много чего наверчено с `Queue`, то обходной маневр - вызвать `Synchronize` в конце, вся очередь вытеснится